# mapping labels to RGB in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

How can we map integer labels to different pseudo-colors in tensorflow. I tried:

```
with sess.as_default():
a = tf.random_uniform(shape=[3,3,3],minval=0,maxval=5,dtype=tf.int32)
keys = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
values = [0,10,20,30,40,50]
table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys, values), -1)
out = table.lookup(a)
table.init.run()
print(out.eval())
```

But this option doesn't solve my use-case. For each unique label in the input tensor [height x width x channels=1], I want to map it to [height x width x channels =3 ]

```
labels                LUT
-------               ----
   0                 [0,0,0]
   1                 [128,64,128]
   2                 [64,128,256]
   3                 [255,64,128]
```

Appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` to map the `labels` to `LUT` table:

```
LUT = tf.constant([[0,0,0],[128,64,128],[64,128,256],[255,64,128]], tf.int32)
labels = [0, 1, 2, 3]
out = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(LUT, labels)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(out))

#[[  0   0   0]
# [128  64 128]
# [ 64 128 256]
# [255  64 128]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete example using Google Colab (Links on the bottom)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.colab import drive
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

drive.mount('/content/drive')

sess = tf.Session()

# an input image

img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/test.png')
img = img[:, :, 0]
print(img.shape)

label = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[None,None])

LUTval = np.zeros((256,3)) # lookup table must span all possible labels, classes are 0 to 19, 255 is unlabelled in this example
LUTval[0:19, :] = [[128, 64, 128],[244, 35, 232],[70, 70, 70],[102, 102, 156],[190, 153, 153],[153, 153, 153],[250, 170, 30],[220, 220, 0],[107, 142, 35],[152, 251, 152],[70, 130, 180],[220, 20, 60],[255, 0, 0],[0, 0, 142],[0, 0, 70],[0, 60, 100],[0, 80, 100],[0, 0, 230],[119, 11, 32]]
LUT = tf.constant(LUTval, tf.int32)
col = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(LUT, label)

res_col = sess.run(col, feed_dict = {label: img})

print(res_col.shape)

#img2 = img[:,:,::-1]
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(np.array(res_col).astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

[Snippet on Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bCHOUwLJMvFjxJMqcy9M6de8d5_jXlCW)
[Test Image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mdz0K_YAEvR5xVdSQUQlTnfnq9HqvtjC)